# Updating internal interface-to-type resolution

Tags: interface, phpstorm, code-inspection

While working with a PHP project and updating an interface while the implementing class is open in a different tab, I often encounter that the implementation is *invalidated* due to changes in the signature of the method (e.g parameter type is changed). The implementation gets an annoying red underline also even if the method is renamed.

If I restart the editor then the method is no longer marked as invalid. This leads me to believe that the resolution of the contract is stale or outdated. Actually, I just discovered that if I wait for a while (e.g while writing this question and going back to make a screen shot), then the interface is resolved correctly. Thus I think that some indexing process in PhpStorm is running in the background.

My question is: How can I trigger the interface <-> implementation resolution at whim or increase the frequency of those periodic re-scans.

The filesystem is ext4, mounted locally:

```
/dev/mapper/balmora-root on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
```

PhpStorm is 9.0.2

Comment: Does simple `File | Synchronize...` makes any difference? Or `Code | Inspect Code...` on such file(s)?

Answer (score 1):

> Actually, I just discovered that if I wait for a while (e.g while writing this question and going back to make a screen shot), then the interface is resolved correctly.

Please try `File | Synchronize...` to force IDE re-reading project files looking for changes.

If it does not help -- use `Code | Inspect Code...` on problematic file(s) to force full re-parse of such file(s).

Comment: This is a work-around, I'd like to not worry about that stuff at all and to understand why the IDE fails at "watching" the files.